# How can I pre-select choices in my custom DRF MultipleChoiceField from a model m2m relation?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

My `Book` model can have `Tag` models associated with it through a m2m relationship, these tags in turns are always further categorised through a FK `TagCategory` model.

```py
class TagCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=TagCategory, ...)

class Book(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(to=Tag, ...)
```

Using serializers from DRF, I want the `BookSerializer` to offer a `MultipleChoiceField` for the end user to select a number of tags from. If I use `serializers.ModelSerializer` and don't touch anything, it works all right.

But I actually want to group the tags / choices by category, which is not the default behaviour, so I have to define my own `MultipleChoiceField` and do the grouping of choices in `choices` and remind the field to get its `source` from the correct attribute of the `Book` model:

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags_input = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[
            [category.name, [[tag.pk, tag.name]
                for tag in category.tags.all()]] for category in Category.objects.all()],
        source="tags",
        write_only=True,
    )
    fields = ("tags_input",)
```

This seems to work well for creating a `Book` model and assigning tags through m2m. However, when serializing an existing model with tags for updating, the initial tags / choices are not pre-selected as expected. Setting `initial="tags"` does not seem to change anything.

How can I successfully retrieve and pre-select tags / choices from `Book.tags` when serializing the model?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my confusion here was to think that `ModelSerializer` would actually use `MultipleChoiceField`, so I could beat it to it and define it myself: no. `tags` is a m2m relationship, so I need a `RelatedField` with `many=True` somewhere.

First of all, since I'm serializing AND deserializing from the same model field, I should NOT do the `tags_input` workaround I came up with. I need one field that does everything:

```py
class TagChoiceRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    queryset = Tags.objects.all()

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.pk

    def get_choices(self, cutoff=None):
        return {
            category.name:
                {tag.pk: tag.name for tag in category.tags.all()}
            for category in TagCategory.objects.all()
        }

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            tag = self.get_queryset().get(pk=data)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError()

        return tag

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagChoiceRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ("tags",)
```

The serializer now uses the field to:

- expectedly serialize each tag with its pk (to_representation)
- expectedly deserializes each tag with a pk (to_internal_value)
- nicely group tags/choices according to their category (get_choices)
- finally initialize the latter with the book instance's tags if applicable (something internal)